# FontAwesome served by Nginx only *sometimes* broken in Safari, until browser reset?

Tags: css, nginx, safari, font-awesome, macrabbit-espresso

I'm using Font Awesome. Sometimes - and I haven't figured out the pattern yet, unfortunately - the icons aren't working in Safari. When this happens, Safari shows the standard icon for a missing character, the outline of a box.

When I reset the browser, Font Awesome works as expected. And then, after some time, it reverts to not working again.

I'm serving Font Awesome from Nginx. That *could* be relevant, because I originally served these files without the proper headers, which broke Font Awesome in Safari. I'm wondering if maybe somehow Safari could have cached the non-header versions of the files, and maybe somehow keeps using them even when cache is cleared (maybe it's caching fonts somewhere else? But why would it revert to the broken version?).

Okay, this isn't much to go on I know, but any ideas, has anyone else experienced this? Thank you! :)

Edited to add screenshot of broken behavior:

[image]

Comment: does a ctrl+f5 (or whatever safari uses to reload cache) fix it ? also does the issue happen on different browsers or just safari? did you try doing a 'clear cache' from safari settings.

Comment: Reloading cache fixes it in the short term - but then the problem comes back later. I've been seeing it a lot today. Chrome and Firefox are fine - it's just Safari, and the browser the program MacRabbit's Espresso uses (I believe it's somehow tied to Safari)

Comment: its probably safari related since it only happens on safari, to help us next time you see those broken images try to see what the browser console says, are they 404's or different url's or what, that would help

Comment: Hi Mohammed - thanks for the comment. They aren't broken images; they're broken fonts. The browser is displaying the outline of a box that shows when a font character is missing. I've just updated my question to include a screenshot. The browser console doesn't display an error - is there somewhere else I could see an error reported?

Comment: well there's nothing I can think of as a cause of this problem right now, but you can check your server's access log and grep for the font file and see if it ever returns a different response code or something, other than that i don't think I could help much unless we find a pattern or a way to reproduce this problem, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. I'm on the hunt. :)